# Terminal improper output, unprintable character

Tags: command-line, 16.04, gnome-terminal, vnstat

Ever since I have used vnstat and vnstati, not a single time have I received a proper date under the day column for vnstat. Also, vnstati screenshots display unprintable characters.
Please help me solve this problem.

Screenshots:

1:vnstat

[image]

2:vnstati

[image]

Thank you

Comment: What output do you get with the `date` command?

Comment: @heynnema
I get the date correctly:
Output: Wed Nov  2 20:19:41 IST 2016

Comment: Look at /etc/vnstat.conf and you'll find formatting detail there. Otherwise, use Synaptic to do a "complete removal" and reinstall vnstat. Report back.

Comment: @heynnema thanks for replying. Here's what I did:
1. Looked at /etc/vnstat.conf , date format was %x
2. Reinstalled vnstat using dpkg (purge).
3. Removed vnstat using synaptic as you recommended, restarted the system and installed vnstat using synaptic again.
But all this to no good. Problem still exists.

Comment: In terminal preferences/encodings do you have UTF-8 selected? Do you have any other languages installed? Check "Language Support" in System Settings.

Comment: I checked terminal encoding using [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306153/how-to-get-terminals-character-encoding). It was set to en_IN. I changed it to "en_IN.utf8".  Under language support I have English, English(US) and  English(India)(regional language). Still no good.

Comment: How does it look in the Terminal app preference/encoding tab?

Comment: I went to Language Support and changed my regional formats to English (US) and then apply system wide. And the problem is solved now. I guess there is some problem in ubuntu language pack for my region. Anyway, thank you so much for helping @heynnema.

Comment: Great news! I added our conversation as an answer. Please vote/accept it if our conversation was helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a brief conversation in the comments...

1. we checked the output of the `date` command
2. we checked the date format configuration in the `/etc/vnstat.conf` file
3. we checked the Terminal app preferences in the encoding tab
4. we checked the language settings in System Settings/Language Support

It was found that by setting the Language Support regional format *(from India)* to `English (US)` and applying it system wide, fixed the problem with vnstat displaying odd characters in the date field.

A log out may be necessary for the changes to take effect. :)